# Display message if zip code is servicable

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, zipcode

if we go for cart page, we can see an option to find shipping charges by entering zip code.

[image]

we allowed only some zip codes to place an order.

1)if we enter zip code than along with shipping charges, it should display

message "**Shipping is Available**"

2)if that zip code is not exists , than it should display **"Shipping is Not Available"**

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml

<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2014 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<?php /** @var $this Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Shipping */ ?>
<div class="shipping">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Estimate Shipping and Tax') ?></h2>
    <div class="shipping-form">
       <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/estimatePost') ?>" method="post" id="shipping-zip-form">
            <p><?php echo $this->__('Enter your destination to get a shipping estimate.') ?></p>
            <ul class="form-list">
                <li>
                    <label for="country" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Country') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <?php echo Mage::getBlockSingleton('directory/data')->getCountryHtmlSelect($this->getEstimateCountryId()) ?>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php //if($this->getStateActive()): ?>
                <li>
                    <label for="region_id"<?php if ($this->isStateProvinceRequired()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php if ($this->isStateProvinceRequired()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <select id="region_id" name="region_id" title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" style="display:none;"<?php echo ($this->isStateProvinceRequired() ? ' class="validate-select"' : '') ?>>
                            <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('Please select region, state or province') ?></option>
                        </select>
                       <script type="text/javascript">
                       //<![CDATA[
                           $('region_id').setAttribute('defaultValue',  "<?php echo $this->getEstimateRegionId() ?>");
                       //]]>
                       </script>
                       <input type="text" id="region" name="region" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getEstimateRegion()) ?>"  title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" class="input-text" style="display:none;" />
                   </div>
                </li>
            <?php //endif; ?>
            <?php if($this->getCityActive()): ?>
                <li>
                    <label for="city"<?php if ($this->isCityRequired()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php if ($this->isCityRequired()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo $this->__('City') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input class="input-text<?php if ($this->isCityRequired()):?> required-entry<?php endif;?>" id="city" type="text" name="estimate_city" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getEstimateCity()) ?>" />
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
                <li>
                    <label for="postcode"<?php if ($this->isZipCodeRequired()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php if ($this->isZipCodeRequired()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input class="input-text validate-postcode<?php if ($this->isZipCodeRequired()):?> required-entry<?php endif;?>" type="text" id="postcode" name="estimate_postcode" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getEstimatePostcode()) ?>" />
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="buttons-set">
                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Get a Quote') ?>" onclick="coShippingMethodForm.submit()" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Get a Quote') ?></span></span></button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            new RegionUpdater('country', 'region', 'region_id', <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>);
        //]]>
        </script>

        <?php if (($_shippingRateGroups = $this->getEstimateRates())): ?>
        <form id="co-shipping-method-form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/estimateUpdatePost') ?>">
            <dl class="sp-methods">
                <?php foreach ($_shippingRateGroups as $code => $_rates): ?>
                    <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getCarrierName($code)) ?></dt>
                    <dd>
                        <ul>
                        <?php foreach ($_rates as $_rate): ?>
                            <li<?php if ($_rate->getErrorMessage()) echo ' class="error-msg"';?>>
                               <?php if ($_rate->getErrorMessage()): ?>
                                    <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getErrorMessage()) ?>
                               <?php else: ?>
                                    <input name="estimate_method" type="radio" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getCode()) ?>" id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"<?php if($_rate->getCode()===$this->getAddressShippingMethod()) echo ' checked="checked"' ?> class="radio" />
                                    <label for="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getMethodTitle()) ?>
                                    <?php $_excl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), $this->helper('tax')->displayShippingPriceIncludingTax()); ?>
                                    <?php $_incl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), true); ?>
                                    <?php echo $_excl; ?>
                                    <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayShippingBothPrices() && $_incl != $_excl): ?>
                                        (<?php echo $this->__('Incl. Tax'); ?> <?php echo $_incl; ?>)
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    </label>
                               <?php endif ?>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </dd>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </dl>
            <div class="buttons-set">
                <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Update Total') ?>" class="button" name="do" value="<?php echo $this->__('Update Total') ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Update Total') ?></span></span></button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            var coShippingMethodForm = new VarienForm('shipping-zip-form');
            var countriesWithOptionalZip = <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getCountriesWithOptionalZip(true) ?>;

            coShippingMethodForm.submit = function () {
                var country = $F('country');
                var optionalZip = false;

                for (i=0; i < countriesWithOptionalZip.length; i++) {
                    if (countriesWithOptionalZip[i] == country) {
                        optionalZip = true;
                    }
                }
                if (optionalZip) {
                    $('postcode').removeClassName('required-entry');
                }
                else {
                    $('postcode').addClassName('required-entry');
                }
                return VarienForm.prototype.submit.bind(coShippingMethodForm)();
            }
        //]]>
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In estimatePostAction add code and check zipcode

```
public function estimatePostAction()
    {
        $country    = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('country_id');
        $postcode   = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('estimate_postcode');
        $city       = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('estimate_city');
        $regionId   = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('region_id');
        $region     = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('region');

        $zipArray = array('12345','67890',...);

        if(in_array($postcode,$zipArray)){
              Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMyShipMessage('Ship is available.');
         }else{
              Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMyShipMessage('Ship is not available.');             
         }

        $this->_getQuote()->getShippingAddress()
            ->setCountryId($country)
            ->setCity($city)
            ->setPostcode($postcode)
            ->setRegionId($regionId)
            ->setRegion($region)
            ->setCollectShippingRates(true);
        $this->_getQuote()->save();
        $this->_goBack();
    }
```

In your template file between

```
<?php if (($_shippingRateGroups = $this->getEstimateRates())): 

       if(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMyShipMessage()){
             echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMyShipMessage();
             Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsMyShipMessage();
        }

endif; ?>
```

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in "if(in_array($postcode,$zipArray){"`

Comment: search for text "Prashant" in these files

Default.phtml = > http://pastebin.com/nNy73Ukb , 

carcontroller.php file = > http://pastebin.com/cTF6gaKx

Comment: Sorry my mistake i forgot to complete if statement i have updated code try with it

Comment: Echo session in template and check have any value or null

Comment: please search for "prashant" here : http://pastebin.com/

Comment: please check whether i echoed correctly or not

Comment: <?php if (($_shippingRateGroups = $this->getEstimateRates())): remove this condition and check

Comment: before trying your latest code, i am getting message "Ship is not available" for all zip codes

Comment: $zipArray = array('12345','67890'); add all zip code which have shipping available in array

Comment: @PrashantValanda How can i get shipping zip code for shipping condition?